# Modular Exponentiation by Squaring and large exponents

Tags: algorithms, cryptography

I have been thinking about the [exponentiation by squaring algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). The algorithm obviously takes  $\mathcal{O}({\log(n) \cdot \log^2(m)})$ time for the computation of some $x^n \pmod m$.

The Handbook of Applied Cryptography assumes for the exponent $n$ that $n < m$ to give a runtime of $\mathcal{O}(\log^3(m))$.

So how can we handle exponents bigger than $m$? We could use the base version of the first paragraph and get $\mathcal{O}({\log(n) \cdot \log^2(m)})$ runtime.

But would it be an option to first reduce the exponent $n$ by replacing it with the residue of $\frac{n}{m-1}?$ This is possible due to elementary group theory and should take $\mathcal{O}(\log(\lfloor \frac{n}{m-1} \rfloor) \cdot \log(m-1))$ bit operations.
So in total this would mean a runtime of $\mathcal{O}(\log(\lfloor\frac{n}{m-1}\rfloor) \cdot \log(m-1)) + \mathcal{O}(\log^3(m)) = \mathcal{O}(\log(\lfloor\frac{n}{m-1}\rfloor) \cdot \log(m-1) + \log^3(m))$.

Can this runtime be seen as an improvement ?

Comment: Ignoring the setup and just comparing the two asymptotic results, yes, this is asymptotically better when $\log(n) \gg \log(m)$ (note that this is much stronger than $n \gg m$, for example $\log(m^2) \not \gg \log(m)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exponents bigger than $m$ do not occur in practice, as $x^n$ is cylic with period $\phi(m) < m$. Moreover, in crypto (like RSA or DH) we always assured of $n < m$ when working mod $m$, just by how the systems work. So your concern for runtimes when $n>m$ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this if you know that $m$ is prime (which is not the case if, for instance, $m$ is the exponent in a public RSA key). In general, you have to reduce $n$ modulo $\varphi(m)$, which is equal to $m-1$ only if $m$ is prime.

Comment: Could you please explain why in factoring we have $14^{105} \bmod 5 = (((14^3)^5)^7)$. Then we have $14^3\equiv 4\ mod\ 5$, then $4^5\equiv 4\ mod\ 5$?